# Edit referenced project config without rebuilding

Tags: java, maven, build, config

My application has 2 projects: Web and DAO. In DAO project I have a config file that contains DB connection string. The DAO project is packaged as jar and referenced by the Web project. The Web project is packaged as war. I built these 2 projects with maven:

`mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

After deploying the war file, I want to change the connection string. But I found that the DAO project is included as a jar file, and I cannot edit the connection string. How could I build the application so that I can edit the connection string without rebuilding the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting your db connection (I assume url includes also user/pwd) in the JAR is no good practice at all, because you force each admin to make the database fit your requirements. But it should be vice versa.

To reach this, do not put your config-file into the JAR. Instead let your code read a defined system-property or env which must contain the path to the config file.

So you define the name of the system-property or env and the admin can fill this with the path to the config.

You can give him te example config file as a template and he can edit connection string and other stuff to meet the system requirements.